# Mac installer package - how to optionally install to multiple locations

Tags: deployment, productbuild, pkgbuild

I am trying to create a Mac installer package with `pkgbuild` and `productbuild` that installs 1 package to 4 locations optionally, depending on the result of the installer options laid out in the distribution definition xml file.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way of customising the `Distribution.xml` to install a package more than once.

The only alternative I can see is bundling 4 identical packages, but with separate install 
locations; however this is undesirable as it would make my installer unnecessarily large.

Is there another way of achieving this custom behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `--component "/Applications/SomeApp.app"`

use `--root ./basefolder` and have root-like structure (example: 'Applications','Library' folders)

```
 /usr/bin/pkgbuild --scripts ./scripts --info PackageInfo --identifier com.app.installer --root ./basefolder "Installer.pkg"
```

http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/Ivanhoe/FLAT.html is helpful in creating PackageInfo file